# How do I update individual fields in nested objects that are in arrays in MongoDB using Mongoose?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, nested, nosql

This is my first post so please bear with me. I am building a LinkedIn clone and I am trying to keep track of the work experience, projects and courses of the users, and those will be kept in an array of objects inside of the `User` schema. Now let's say a user will try to add or update one of the elements in one of those arrays, I have the user ID and I am passing it to `findOneAndUpdate()` as the filter.

Here is my User schema:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user_id: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'User ID required.'],
    unique: true,
    immutable: true,
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Name required.'],
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Email required.'],
    unique: true,
    lowercase: true,
    immutable: true,
  },
  title: {
    type: String,
  },
  location: {
    type: String,
  },
  phone_number: {
    type: String,
  },
  contact_email: {
    type: String,
  },
  photo: {
    type: String,
  },
  website: {
    type: String,
  },
  backdrop: {
    type: String,
  },
  summary: {
    type: String,
  },
  work: {
    type: String,
  },
  connections: {
    type: Number,
  },
  projects: [
    {
      title: {
        type: String,
      },
      description: {
        type: String,
      },
      start_date: {
        type: Date,
      },
      end_date: {
        type: Date,
      },
      technologies: {
        type: String,
      },
      picture: {
        type: String,
      },
    },
  ],
  skills: [{
    skill: {
      name: {
        type: String,
      },
      level: {
        type: String,
      },
    },
  }],
  experience: [
    {
      company: {
        type: String,
      },
      logo: {
        type: String,
      },
      title: {
        type: String,
      },
      location: {
        type: String,
      },
      start_date: {
        type: Date,
      },
      end_date: {
        type: Date,
      },
      description: {
        type: String,
      },
    },
  ],
  education: [
    {
      school: {
        type: String,
      },
      logo: {
        type: String,
      },
      degree: {
        type: String,
      },
      location: {
        type: String,
      },
      start_date: {
        type: Date,
      },
      end_date: {
        type: Date,
      },
      description: {
        type: String,
      },
    },
  ],
  languages: [
    {
      name: {
        type: String,
      },
      level: {
        type: String,
      },
    },
  ],
  awards: [
    {
      title: {
        type: String,
      },
      date: {
        type: Date,
      },
      awarder: {
        type: String,
      },
      summary: {
        type: String,
      },
    },
  ],
  courses: [
    {
      title: {
        type: String,
      },
      number: {
        type: String,
      },
      school: {
        type: String,
      },
      start_date: {
        type: Date,
      },
      end_date: {
        type: Date,
      },
      description: {
        type: String,
      },
    },
  ],

});
```

And in my `UserController.ts` file, I tried using this:

```
const updateUser = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    const filter = { user_id: req.body.user_id };
    const update = req.body;
    const updatedUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, {
      new: true,
      upsert: true,
    });
    res.status(201).json({
      status: 'success',
      data: {
        user: updatedUser,
      },
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({
      status: `ERROR: ${err}`,
      message: 'error updating user',
    });
  }
};
```

And in my request using the format of the schema but that didn't work out as expected. I know mongoose will automatically give it an _id field to each of the individual objects in the array, but again, I have had no luck updating them. I tried sending a PATCH request with this as the body to add a skill like so:

```
{
    "user_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "title": "Mr.",
    "skills" : {
        "name": "Flute",
        "level": "Novice"

    }
}
```

And this was the response I got. It created a skill but didnt add the data in the skill object:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "user": {
            "_id": "63d3715f2ef9698667230a53",
            "user_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "name": "Jonathan Abitbol",
            "email": "yoniabitbol1@gmail.com",
            "projects": [],
            "skills": [
                {
                    "_id": "63d4068d2df30c9e943e4608"
                }
            ],
            "experience": [],
            "education": [],
            "languages": [],
            "awards": [],
            "courses": [],
            "__v": 0,
            "title": "Mr."
        }
    }
}
```

Any help on how to add/edit the nested objects would be appreciated.

Comment: That code looks reasonable.  What does "didn't work out" mean?

Comment: Ive added more detail to make it clearer, let me know if this clarifies things! Thank you! @Joe

Comment: The `skills` field in the schema is an array, I don't think mongoose will implicitly push if you try to set it to an object, and it may remove that field from the update for not matching the schema.